# Definition of convergence rate of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, definition

What is the definition of rate of convergence of a sequence of random variables? i.e. what does it mean that the convergence rate of the sequence of random variable $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n,\ldots$ to $X$ is $g(n)$?

Is the convergence rate unique? Does it depend on the type of convergence?

I thought the definition would be: the convergence rate of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n,\ldots$ to $X$ is $g(n)$ if for large enough $n$,
$$
|X_n-X|=O(g(n))
$$

Comment: Convergence rate for which kind of convergence?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I wasn't sure if it depended on the type of convergence... say in $\mathcal{L}^2$ i.e. $E[(X_n−X)^2] \rightarrow 0$.